# Did the installation fail? (make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install'.)

Tags: make

I have tried to install Qt Cross compilation for  Raspberry zero with my LMDE Linux OS (Lenovo Laptop) based on [these instructions](https://mechatronicsblog.com/cross-compile-and-deploy-qt-5-12-for-raspberry-pi/), using this script I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash

./configure -release -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/home/so/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot /home/so/raspi/sysroot -opensource -confirm-license -skip qtwayland -skip qtlocation -skip qtscript -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -extprefix /home/so/raspi/qt5pi -hostprefix /home/so/raspi/qt5 -no-use-gold-linker -v -no-gbm


 make
 make install
```

and saved as **instlation_qt.sh** file. I ran it using

```
sudo ./instlation_qt.sh
```

At the end of the output, I have this:

```
so/Desktop/trash/3/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qtbase/bin/qmake -install qinstall /home/so/Desktop/trash/3/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qttranslations/translations/qtxmlpatterns_pl.qm /home/so/raspi/qt5pi/translations/qtxmlpatterns_pl.qm
/home/so/Desktop/trash/3/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qtbase/bin/qmake -install qinstall /home/so/Desktop/trash/3/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qttranslations/translations/qtxmlpatterns_ru.qm /home/so/raspi/qt5pi/translations/qtxmlpatterns_ru.qm
/home/so/Desktop/trash/3/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qtbase/bin/qmake -install qinstall /home/so/Desktop/trash/3/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qttranslations/translations/qtxmlpatterns_sk.qm /home/so/raspi/qt5pi/translations/qtxmlpatterns_sk.qm
/home/so/Desktop/trash/3/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qtbase/bin/qmake -install qinstall /home/so/Desktop/trash/3/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qttranslations/translations/qtxmlpatterns_uk.qm /home/so/raspi/qt5pi/translations/qtxmlpatterns_uk.qm
/home/so/Desktop/trash/3/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qtbase/bin/qmake -install qinstall /home/so/Desktop/trash/3/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qttranslations/translations/qtxmlpatterns_zh_TW.qm /home/so/raspi/qt5pi/translations/qtxmlpatterns_zh_TW.qm
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/so/Desktop/trash/3/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qttranslations/translations'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/so/Desktop/trash/3/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qttranslations'
cd qtdoc/ && ( test -e Makefile || /home/so/Desktop/trash/3/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qtbase/bin/qmake -o Makefile /home/so/Desktop/trash/3/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qtdoc/qtdoc.pro ) && make -f Makefile install
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/so/Desktop/trash/3/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qtdoc'
cd doc/ && ( test -e Makefile || /home/so/Desktop/trash/3/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qtbase/bin/qmake -o Makefile /home/so/Desktop/trash/3/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qtdoc/doc/doc.pro ) && make -f Makefile install
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/so/Desktop/trash/3/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qtdoc/doc'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/so/Desktop/trash/3/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qtdoc/doc'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/so/Desktop/trash/3/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qtdoc'
```

I have a new  `~/raspi/qt5pi` folder as described in `./configure ...  -extprefix /home/so/raspi/qt5pi ...` .

I think the installation process end successfully [based on this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937345/make-install-error-nothing-to-be-done). Did the installation process successfully complete?

OR

I have a problem in cross-compilation Qt project to my raspberry zero and get this error:

```
  19:22:40: Starting /home/pi/Desktop/test_3/bin/test_3 ...
    libEGL warning: DRI3: xcb_connect failed
    libEGL warning: DRI2: xcb_connect failed
    libEGL warning: DRI2: xcb_connect failed
    Could not initialize egl display
```

So I suspect that there is some problem. I have seen [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561640/make-nothing-to-be-done-for-all/8562379#8562379) and I think there is some problem. Does the

> make[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561640/make-nothing-to-be-done-for-all/8562379#8562379): Nothing to be done for 'install'.

message come from a mistake in writing the `make install` command like:

1. not having `sudo` before it?
2. based on this site, something like:

> be caused by spaces the before command in makefile rule instead of tab ...

3. or any other things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The “Nothing to be done for ‘install’.” message refers to a small part of the installation:

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/so/Desktop/trash/3/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qtdoc/doc'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install'.
```

This says that there was nothing to do in the `qtdoc/doc` directory only.

Lines above that such as

```
/home/so/Desktop/trash/3/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qtbase/bin/qmake -install qinstall /home/so/Desktop/trash/3/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qttranslations/translations/qtxmlpatterns_ru.qm /home/so/raspi/qt5pi/translations/qtxmlpatterns_ru.qm
/home/so/Desktop/trash/3/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qtbase/bin/qmake -install qinstall /home/so/Desktop/trash/3/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qttranslations/translations/qtxmlpatterns_sk.qm /home/so/raspi/qt5pi/translations/qtxmlpatterns_sk.qm
/home/so/Desktop/trash/3/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qtbase/bin/qmake -install qinstall /home/so/Desktop/trash/3/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qttranslations/translations/qtxmlpatterns_uk.qm /home/so/raspi/qt5pi/translations/qtxmlpatterns_uk.qm
/home/so/Desktop/trash/3/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qtbase/bin/qmake -install qinstall /home/so/Desktop/trash/3/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3/qttranslations/translations/qtxmlpatterns_zh_TW.qm /home/so/raspi/qt5pi/translations/qtxmlpatterns_zh_TW.qm
```

show that files *were* installed successfully.

If the overall installation had failed, your `make install` run would have ended with an error such as

```
make: *** [Makefile:20: install] Error 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer.